# Trying to return AREL not Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel, active-relation

I have two models: Products and Tags through a products_tags join in a HABTM relationship.

I am currently defining my controller index as:

```
@stats = Product.all(:include => :tags).uniq
```

which returns an array. How can I return an Active Rel object? I tried added scoped, however received a no method error.

I need to find and list a unique list of tags, and be able to view what product each specif tag belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Try `@stats = Product.includes(:tags).uniq`.

Note that `uniq` turns the Relation into an Array; if you want to do something like `SELECT DISTINCT` you'll want to use `Product.includes(:tags).select('DISTINCT whatever')`.

Comment: My apologies, updating the answer

Comment: Now im getting a `Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'cat_name' `. Do I need to somehow include my join table?

Comment: What is your full line? You can see the SQL that would be generated by going into the console and appending `.to_sql` to the end of your scope, which may aid in debugging.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM `products` ` is the SQL being generated. Its selecting it from the products table, however the cat_name is a field on the tags table. I tried `Product.includes(:tags).select('DISTINCT tags.cat_name')` but that freezes my console.